# how to read and display json data in text file using c#

Tags: c#, json

i really needs all the helps available now.

Objective: How to read Json Data in normal text file putting the specific text into String variable?
Coding platform: visual studio 2010
Language: C#

below is the example json data in my normal text file

```
{
"created_at":"Sun May 05 14:12:21 +0000 2013",
"id":331048726577692674,
"id_str":"331048726577692674",
"text":"Why play Luiz at CB?",
"user":
    {
        "id":458765935,
        "id_str":"458765935",
        "name":"Amrit Singhpong",
        "screen_name":"AmritTheBlue",
        "location":"Stamford Bridge",
        "url":null,
        "description":"17. Chelsea fan! XO Care Free",
         }
}
```

Right now all i can do is to only read all the lines in the text file and place it into the array i created to store each and every lines.
So supposing this whole example of json data is stored in a single array, my next problem would be, How do i take out the "text":"Why play Luiz at CB?" and place it into a normal string variable?

Comment: Use JSON.net to parse the JSON data: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx you wont need to write the custom JSON parser yourself.

Comment: Looks like the data is returned by Twitter API... :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use .NET JavaScriptSerializer();

```
 { "created_at" : "Sun May 05 14:12:21 +0000 2013",
      "id" : 331048726577692674,
      "id_str" : "331048726577692674",
      "text" : "Why play Luiz at CB?",
      "user" : { "description" : "17. Chelsea fan! XO Care Free",
          "id" : 458765935,
          "id_str" : "458765935",
          "location" : "Stamford Bridge",
          "name" : "Amrit Singhpong",
          "screen_name" : "AmritTheBlue",
          "url" : null
        }
    }

    string JSON = File.ReadAllText("JSON.txt");
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    object str = serializer.DeserializeObject(JSON);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your options:

- [JSON.NET](http://json.net) (most powerful)
- [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) (in the framework)